# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "42321"(it is about converting date from excel format to java format, not about DateFormat.parse.)

Tags: java, excel

I am taking data from xlsx file, The data of xlsx file like below.

```
1   1   13/11/15    00:00:02    3   42.61   xxxx to xxxx    9   2   2 Axle Truck or Bus
2   1   13/11/15    00:00:12    1   27.11   xxxx to xxxx    3   2   3 Wheeler
3   1   13/11/15    00:00:15    3   22.65   xxxx to xxxx    7   2   LMV 2 Axle Light Motor Vehicle
4   1   13/11/15    00:00:21    2   18.76   xxxx to xxxx    7   2   LMV 2 Axle Light Motor Vehicle
5   1   13/11/15    00:00:21    3   18.76   xxxx to xxxx    9   2   2 Axle Truck or Bus
```

from this data i am reading row wise and inserting into DataBase by using below code.

but the problem is i am not able to get date of 3rd column from xlsx file but am getting remaining to print.

below one is my code:

```
processOneSheet("C:/Users/Penchalaiah/Desktop/New folder/"+hs.getAttribute("filename1"));
        System.out.println(hs.getAttribute("filename1"));
        System.out.println("clossing the connnection");
        ps.close();
        con1.close();
        System.out.println("execution completed");
        //request.setAttribute("message","THE XLSX DATA TRANSFERRED SUCCEFULLY");
        // request.getRequestDispatcher("/HomePage.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    /*try {
        ps.close();
        con1.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/


}



public void processOneSheet(String filename) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("executing Process Method");
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

    XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

    // To look up the Sheet Name / Sheet Order / rID,
    //  you need to process the core Workbook stream.
    // Normally it's of the form rId# or rSheet#
    InputStream sheet2 = r.getSheet("rId2");
    System.out.println("Sheet2");
    InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet2);
    parser.parse(sheetSource);
    sheet2.close();
}



public XMLReader fetchSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sst) throws SAXException {
    XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
    ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst);
    parser.setContentHandler(handler);
    return parser;
}

/** 
 * See org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler javadocs 
 */
private  class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private SharedStringsTable sst;
    private String lastContents;
    private boolean nextIsString;

    String TxnNo;
    String SurveyId;
    Date date;
    String Time;
    String Lane;
    String Avspeed;
    String Direction;
    String VehicleCategory;
    String Axle_count;
    String Vehicle;


    int i = 1;

    private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst) {
        this.sst = sst;

    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // c => cell
        if(name.equals("c")) {
            // Print the cell reference
            //System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");
            // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                nextIsString = true;
            } else {
                nextIsString = false;
            }
        }
        // Clear contents cache
        lastContents = "";
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        // Process the last contents as required.
        // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
        if(nextIsString) {
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
            lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
            nextIsString = false;
        }
        // v => contents of a cell
        // Output after we've seen the string contents
        if(name.equals("v")) {

            if(i == 1){
                TxnNo = lastContents;
            }
            if(i == 2){
                SurveyId = lastContents;
            }
            if(i == 3){
                try {
 //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH).parse(lastContents);
//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
                    System.out.println("The Date is: "+date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 4){
                Time = lastContents;
                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 5){
                Lane = lastContents;
                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 6){
                Avspeed = lastContents;
                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 7){
                Direction = lastContents;
                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 8){
                VehicleCategory = lastContents;
                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 9){
                Axle_count = lastContents;
                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
            }
            if(i == 10){
                Vehicle = lastContents;
                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");

                //System.out.print(lastContents+"("+i+")");
                insertInToDb(TxnNo, SurveyId, date, Time, Lane, Avspeed,Direction, VehicleCategory, Axle_count, Vehicle);
                i = 0;
            }


            i++;


        }

    }


    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        lastContents += new String(ch, start, length);
    }
}
    int gcc = 0;
    public void insertInToDb(String TxnNo,String SurveyId,Date date, String Time,String Lane,String Avspeed,String Direction, String VehicleCategory, String Axle_count, String Vehicle){

        try {

            ps.setString(1, TxnNo);
            ps.setString(2, SurveyId);
            ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) date);
            ps.setString(4, Time);
            ps.setString(5, Lane);
            ps.setString(6, Avspeed);
            ps.setString(7, Direction);
            ps.setString(8, VehicleCategory);
            ps.setString(9, Axle_count);
            ps.setString(10, Vehicle);
            ps.setString(11, (String)hs.getAttribute("zoneId1"));
            ps.setString(12, (String)hs.getAttribute("location1"));
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

i am getting exception in between //@@@@@@@@@@@@
 //@@@@@@@@@@@
of code shown above
when I am printing date column of string I am getting 42321 this value.

how to convert to date of that column value and insert to database?

Comment: Does `dd/M/yy` work?

Comment: Does dd/M/yy work? – soufrk   by using this i am getting same exception

Comment: Btw, change `if (i == X)` to `switch` - it'd be more efficient and more readable.

Comment: what is this ? what can do this ?  Btw, change if (i == X) to switch

Comment: I don't think that this question is duplicate - it is about converting date from excel format to java format, not about DateFormat.parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores date as day count since January 0, 1900. So you need to create actual date by hand, not just parse.

```
@Test
public void excel() {
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
    cl.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
    cl.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    cl.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);
    cl.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 42321 - 1);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(cl.getTime()));

    double excel = 2.31481481481481E-005;
    cl.set(Calendar.SECOND, (int) Math.round(excel * 86400));
    cl.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) Math.round(excel * 86400 / 60));
    cl.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) Math.round(excel * 86400 / 60 / 60));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(cl.getTime()));
}
```

Output

```
13/11/2015
00:00:02
```

**Edit**

Note `-1` near `43231`, according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214326 there is bug in Excel, so we need to skip non-existing 29/02/1900.

**Edit**

Added time calculation.

Comment: i am also getting 14/11/2015. i need 13/11/15 only not 2015

Comment: @honey1 use "dd/MM/yy" as format string

Comment: with dd/MM/yy i am getting 14/11/15. but what about date

Comment: how to take time? i am taking time from xlsx as string, when i print string it gives 2.31481481481481E-005 . how to get time like as xlsx

Comment: Thank you so much @Mikhail Kuchma ,but i need to print time also same as xlsx

Comment: @honey1 I've added time calculation. Check it pls.

Comment: by using this i am getting this value  00:00:01, but in xlsx file it is 00:00:02, how can i get exact value? is it possible to get the exact value ?

Comment: @honey1 My mistake. Added `Math.round` to get more accurate result.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH , it's working fine.